# Run independent jobs in parallel on multiple servers, with load balancing

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, makefile, pbs

I have some number-crunching jobs that I run in parallel on a cluster. Right now, I'm using `make -j` to run several jobs on a single computer, whilst providing some load balancing - some jobs may be finished faster than the other. When scaling to multiple machines, I just divide the number of jobs evenly to several makefiles, blindly hoping that each makefile will take roughly equal time to finish.

Now, my question is - is there an easy way to run N independent jobs on M machines in parallel, while **providing global load balancing**?

I'm on a Linux (Bullx) cluster where PBS is installed, and there is also GNU parallel (although I've never used that one and it seems to me that it will not load-balance between the computing nodes, after reading through the manual).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have `N` jobs, `M` machines and `K` cores where `M*K < N`. You could submit all the jobs to PBS and get new jobs scheduled as soon as older jobs complete. Though if `N` is huge (> 10000), PBS might bring significant overhead.

Comment: Damn, yes, that is smart and simple. Can't imagine why haven't I thought of that. However, our PBS sometimes takes time to start new tasks (up to say 20 minutes; it is a national supercomputing centre so there are many of us using it), and there is a per-user limit to 1000 scheduled tasks, which is currently less than I need to launch. But brilliant anyway, I'm ashamed I haven't even thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me you need something like Jenkins and the Multijob plugin. 
It will effectively allow you to do what you are asking for there.

Here some extra info: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel can balance jobs on heterogeneous clusters: If one host has 4 cores and another has 64 cores, GNU Parallel will by default spawn 4 jobs on the small machine and 64 jobs on the big machine, and keep 4 (and 64) jobs running on those machines until all jobs have been run.

This ought to be vastly better than simply using makefiles.

Comment: Ok, so how would you schedule such a job with GNU parallel? Could you post a brief example? I have never used GNU parallel before.

Comment: Read through the examples http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Working-as-xargs--n1.-Argument-appending and walk through the tutorial http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html Your command line will love you for it. The section on remote execution is most relevant to you.

Comment: I have been through these tutorials before posting my question. I don't really understand how to run different jobs. I see how to run the same command on multiple hosts, but I don't understand how would that possibly facilitate load balancing?

Comment: `parallel -S $SERVER1,$SERVER2 'sleep {};echo {}' ::: {1..1000};` This will detect number of CPUs on each server and only run that many jobs on each of the servers. If you want to run completely different jobs (and not just vary an argument): `cat commands | parallel -S $SERVER1,$SERVER2;` If it is still unclear, then please edit your question to show at least 3 jobs you want run.

Comment: I'll give it a shot on the cluster and see how that works. Thanks for your effort.